# PHP Stripe ACH verify bank account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Ive following this [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts) in stripe regarding the ACH.

This is the code

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

// get the existing bank account
$bank_account = \Stripe\Customer::retrieveSource(
  'cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs',
  'ba_17SHwa2eZvKYlo2CUx7nphbZ'
);

// verify the account
$bank_account->verify(['amounts' => [32, 45]]);
```

In my local I got this error instead

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Stripe_Customer::retrieveSource()

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `retrieveSource` via `Stripe_Customer`, then you are on a very old version of the stripe-php library which does not have a `retrieveSource` method. More recent versions use the syntax `\Stripe\Customer\::retrieveSource`

If you update your Stripe library to a more recent version you should be able to use `retrieveSource` as in the docs.

Comment: if Im going to use recent version does it affect my old code im using? for example the API? sorry for asking I cant see and compare the old version of API return.

Comment: You won't have to upgrade your API version as it's backwards compatible. You will probably have to update any code that uses the stripe-php library as the bindings will have changed.